# Shared object save and load issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got a script like this for score

```
package
{
public class ScoreHolder
{
    static public var score:Number = 0;
}
}
```

Frame code

```
import ScoreHolder;
function checkButtonsone():void
{
if (fisoneclicked21 && fistwoclicked)
{
    ScoreHolder.score += 10;
    Score_t1.text = ScoreHolder.score.toString();

    acmessage.visible = true;
    acmessage.play();

    gotoAndPlay(116);//LEVEL 2
}
}
```

Now I write high score code but did not work.

Code for Higscore

```
publice var sharedData:SharedObject;
 
 
sharedData = SharedObject.getLocal("snake_info");
        if(sharedData.data.highScore == null){ //if it is being called for the first time it will be null. so change it to 0.
            sharedData.data.highScore = 0;
        }
 
 {
            if(score > sharedData.data.highScore){
                //if score greater than highscore then set highscore = score and save it.
                sharedData.data.highScore = score;
                sharedData.flush();
            }
            //display highscore
        txtHighScore.text = String(sharedData.data.highScore);
```

I get a 1120 error.I think I put the code to wrong side.I can't figure out what should I do.I

Answer (score 0):

Typos. Addressing non-existent variables (probably).

```
public var sharedData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("snake_info");

if (sharedData.data.highScore == null)
{
    //if it is being called for the first time it will be null. so change it to 0.
    sharedData.data.highScore = 0;
}

if (ScoreHolder.score > sharedData.data.highScore)
{
    //if score greater than highscore then set highscore = score and save it.
    sharedData.data.highScore = ScoreHolder.score;
    sharedData.flush();
}

//display highscore
txtHighScore.text = ScoreHolder.score.toString();
```

Comment: Actually if I could fix the today score then I can fix playing high score.Can you check my second message ?